# Is this possible to access struct member by calling instance

Tags: c#, .net, struct, operators, implicit-conversion

I've a question about C# struct. I usually use classes, by struct gives me the possibility to override the `=` operator for assignment.

In my case, I've got a `struct`:

```
public struct ObjectWrap<T>
{
    public T _value;

    public ObjectWrap(T value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator ObjectWrap<T>(T value)
    {
        return new ObjectWrap<T>(value);
    }
}
```

(the whole `struct` code isn't there)

By doing that, it's possible to do such things:

```
ObjectWrap<String> d = "My value";
```

But, it's there possible to access my `struct` value member by calling `struct`, such as

```
!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(d)
```

Else, I've to do an accessor and it's not much "human friendly".

Comment: *implicit operator* can also be overloaded for classes. btw You forgot to conceal your class name `DbField` :-D

Comment: [You can't overload operator=](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx). But you can define an implicit conversion operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Simply turn around the implicit operator. This would by the way work as good on a class too:

```
public static implicit operator T(ObjectWrap<T> value)
{
    return value._value;
}
```

This sample uses the incoming type `T` as return value type, so this work for every type `T` supplied with `ObjectWrapper<T>`.

Comment: No problem. I changed your post a little. Also fixed some code issues I had. This will help future readers. Feel free to rollback if you feel so.